# Retrieve name and information about an installed npm package without installing it

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve information about a npm compatible node package programmatically - specifically its name and peerDependencies.

I'm building a command line tool that accepts a package name that will be directly passed to npm install. Therefore a normal npm package name (like `lodash`) works, GitHub URLs like `lodash/lodash#1234567` work and local file paths like `/my/path/to/a/package` also work.

This makes it hard to retrieve the name of the package that is installed, since the input is first resolved by npm and the resulting dependency name that is written to the package.json file.

I wanted to ask if there is a programmatic way to retrieve information about an npm package that  is compatible with the user running npm install package from their command line, i.e. that offers the following functionality:

- Resolving npm packages from the public and private registry (with all sorts of tag variants such as `package@next`)
- Resolving GitHub dependencies (with all variants, such as commit hashes or tags)
- Resolving tarball URLs
- Resolving local packages in folders or tarballs

Things I have already tried:

- Using `pacote` -> By default it does not use the authentication stored in ~/.npmrc

  - It also would be a very costly dependency in terms of package & dependency size
- Parsing npm's install log (with --json) -> Not documented and appears to change with v7 to no longer contain the name of the installed dependency
- Trying to use npm directly by importing the global module

  - No parseable information about the install process
  - Importing the global module also could be flaky and a local npm dependency would be very costly in terms of size
- Using/Parsing npm show -> Does not work for GitHub URLs or local packages/tarballs

What I'm doing right now:

I'm parsing the package.json before the install and after the install and get the difference in dependencies (there should only be one). This dependency is then the resolved name that I can use to import the package.json and retrieve the list of peerDependencies.

But this feels very hacky and I still have to install the package before getting the info I need.

Therefore I wanted to ask if someone has a better idea to approach this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `npm view` is an alias to `npm show` and as mentioned above it sadly does not work for GitHub URLs or local folders/tarballs.